# FadeIn on click and FadeOut other elements

Tags: jquery, show-hide, fadein, fadeout

The code below shows a modalhides the others depending on which icon you choose. How do I make the elements fade in and out onClick instead of just appear and disappear?

jQuery...

```
$j(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".modal").hide();

  $(".close-button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".modal").fadeOut('fast');
  });
});

function showHide(d) {
  var onediv = document.getElementById(d);
  var divs = ['tree-surgery', 'site-clearance', 'stump-grinding', 'hedge-trimming', 'conservation', 'commercial'];
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if (onediv != document.getElementById(divs[i])) {
      document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  onediv.style.display = 'block';
}
```

HTML...

```
                <!-- modals -->

                <div id="tree-surgery" class="modal">

                </div><!-- end .modal -->
                <div id="site-clearance" class="modal">
                </div><!-- end .modal -->
                <div id="stump-grinding" class="modal">
                </div><!-- end .modal -->
                <div id="hedge-trimming" class="modal">
                </div><!-- end .modal -->
                <div id="conservation" class="modal">
                </div><!-- end .modal -->
                <div id="commercial" class="modal">
                </div><!-- end .modal -->

                <!-- icons -->


                        <a href="javascript:showHide('tree-surgery');">
                        <span>Tree Surgery</span></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell small-12 medium-6 large-4 block">
                        <a href="javascript:showHide('site-clearance');">
                        <span>Site Clearance</span></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell small-12 medium-6 large-4 block">
                        <a href="javascript:showHide('stump-grinding');">
                        <span>Stump Grinding</span></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell small-12 medium-6 large-4 block">
                        <a href="javascript:showHide('hedge-trimming');">
                        <span>Hedge Trimming</span></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell small-12 medium-6 large-4 block">
                        <a href="javascript:showHide('conservation');">
                        <span>Conservation</span></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell small-12 medium-6 large-4 block">
                        <a href="javascript:showHide('commercial');">
                        <span>Commercial</span></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

I've also tried adding .show and .hide classes with opacity transition but this didn't work either.

Comment: Post your `HTML` code.

Comment: On this code, your target is disappearing and appearing again. If you don't want to disappear it, you can remove that id from `divs` array. Or I didn't understand correctly your question.

Comment: @guvenakcbn I think the question i misunderstood. I'm just trying to add fade animation to the modal windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some quick `jQuery` we are able to

1. `fadeIn` the `.modal` with the `id`.
2. target all modal divs that do not have that id and `fadeOut`
   with the help of `jquery-ui`

**In chat it was determined that you are using $j to avoid jQuery conflicts, this version has the jQuery object modified**

```js
$j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
function showHide(d) {
  $j(`#${d}`).fadeIn("fast"); //show the selected one in case its hidden
  $j(`div.modal:not([id=${d}])`).fadeOut("slow");  //fadeOut the others.
}
```

```css
div[id] {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- modals -->

<div id="tree-surgery" class="modal">

</div>
<!-- end .modal -->
<div id="site-clearance" class="modal">
</div>
<!-- end .modal -->
<div id="stump-grinding" class="modal">
</div>
<!-- end .modal -->
<div id="hedge-trimming" class="modal">
</div>
<!-- end .modal -->
<div id="conservation" class="modal">
</div>
<!-- end .modal -->
<div id="commercial" class="modal">
</div>
<!-- end .modal -->

<!-- icons -->
<br />

<a href="javascript:showHide('tree-surgery');">
  <span>Tree Surgery</span></div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="cell small-12 medium-6 large-4 block">
  <a href="javascript:showHide('site-clearance');">
    <span>Site Clearance</span></div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="cell small-12 medium-6 large-4 block">
  <a href="javascript:showHide('stump-grinding');">
    <span>Stump Grinding</span></div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="cell small-12 medium-6 large-4 block">
  <a href="javascript:showHide('hedge-trimming');">
    <span>Hedge Trimming</span></div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="cell small-12 medium-6 large-4 block">
  <a href="javascript:showHide('conservation');">
    <span>Conservation</span></div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="cell small-12 medium-6 large-4 block">
  <a href="javascript:showHide('commercial');">
    <span>Commercial</span></div>
</a>
</div>
```

**Standard jQuery**

```js
function showHide(d) {
  $(`#${d}`).fadeIn("fast"); //show the selected one in case its hidden
  $(`div.modal:not([id=${d}])`).fadeOut("slow");  //fadeOut the others.
}
```

```css
div[id] {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- modals -->

<div id="tree-surgery" class="modal">

</div>
<!-- end .modal -->
<div id="site-clearance" class="modal">
</div>
<!-- end .modal -->
<div id="stump-grinding" class="modal">
</div>
<!-- end .modal -->
<div id="hedge-trimming" class="modal">
</div>
<!-- end .modal -->
<div id="conservation" class="modal">
</div>
<!-- end .modal -->
<div id="commercial" class="modal">
</div>
<!-- end .modal -->

<!-- icons -->
<br />

<a href="javascript:showHide('tree-surgery');">
  <span>Tree Surgery</span></div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="cell small-12 medium-6 large-4 block">
  <a href="javascript:showHide('site-clearance');">
    <span>Site Clearance</span></div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="cell small-12 medium-6 large-4 block">
  <a href="javascript:showHide('stump-grinding');">
    <span>Stump Grinding</span></div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="cell small-12 medium-6 large-4 block">
  <a href="javascript:showHide('hedge-trimming');">
    <span>Hedge Trimming</span></div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="cell small-12 medium-6 large-4 block">
  <a href="javascript:showHide('conservation');">
    <span>Conservation</span></div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="cell small-12 medium-6 large-4 block">
  <a href="javascript:showHide('commercial');">
    <span>Commercial</span></div>
</a>
</div>
```

**Version 1: clickable divs**

```js
$(function() {
  $("div.modal").click(function(e) {
    //this is the clicked div
    showHide(this.id);
    $(this).text(this.id);  //make the content of the div it's id for demonstration purposes
  });
});

function showHide(d) {
  var divs = $(`div.modal:not([id=${d}])`).fadeOut("slow");
  //$(`#${d}`).fadeIn("fast"); //incase you want to fade the clicked one back in.
}
```

```css
div[id] {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="tree-surgery" class="modal"></div>
<div id="site-clearance" class="modal"></div>
<div id="stump-grinding" class="modal"></div>
<div id="hedge-trimming" class="modal"></div>
<div id="conservation" class="modal"></div>
<div id="commercial" class="modal"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I apply this as the clickable divs do not show a separate modal window, instead they hide the other divs.

Comment: I wrote this before you added your HTML.  will modify

Comment: I't doesn't seem to be fading in the modal windows

Comment: Not sure what you mean, are yours all hidden when you start? this code has them all show, then fades in the one you click and fades out the others.

Comment: I see the boxes, but when I click one of them nothing happens.

Comment: I have now turned the `modal` hidden by default.  I think that was the misunderstanding.

Comment: Ah yes, OK I think this is what I'm looking for for, excellent! I will try to implement into my work and let you know how I get on, thank you! :)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me :( i need to show a modal per box, so each then displays a another div to show.

Comment: how do i turn onediv.style.display = 'block'; into a FadeIn ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181360/discussion-between-steve0-and-amesey).